# React with ReactRouter nas PHP hosting

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-hosting

I'm looking for a simple solution to deploy small React app with full React router support (no # urls). I've been using firebase so far, but I need to send an email from form, and used PHP for that. 
Is there a service like firebase but with PHP support? Or can I somehow connect PHP file from other hosting (now I receive an error trying do so)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google cloud functions which allows to connect with the firebase.

For an example

-> ReactApp Form for UI

-> Firebase stores data based on users input through React App.

-> Google cloud function which gets called when there is an event in firebase database for an example (Create, update and delete). You can write logic in function which sends an email through send grid. You can write function in Nodejs and golang.

Example (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid)